# Accessing a hdfs folder

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, bigdata

How can I restrict the access of a particular folder in hdfs. The user should not access the folder either through hue, hive or any other means.

Comment: restrict the permission using `chmod` command. That should work./

Comment: Apart from that any other way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from `chmod`, you can use ACLs (Access Control Lists). With this you can set permissions for files, folders and users.

```
user::rw-
user:bruce:rwx                  #effective:r--
group::r-x                      #effective:r--
group:sales:rwx                 #effective:r--
mask::r--
other::r--
```

Check the link below

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html